# Perforce plugin for Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio, perforce

I like working on Visual Studio Code to the extent that I keep my code opened in both eclipse and code so that I can quickly check out a file and continue development in Code. Does anyone know a plug-in/extension for Code to just do basic checkout operation from Perforce?

Comment: Must it be free (if so, add the [tag:gratis] tag), or do you have a budget?